# How to build a graph from cops and robber problem?

Tags: data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, path-finding

This is a 2 part problem that I have given some thought on.

Problem Statement:

In a m by n rectangular field there is a robber R and two cops C1 and C2. Each of the
three start off at some intial square, and at the beginning of the chase, R, C1, C2 all
know each other's positions.

R makes the first move, then C1 and C2. They can only move up, down, left or right. Some
squares are inaccessible because there is an obstacle present. If C1 or C2 reach a square
that R is on then they catch R.

In order to escape, R must reach a square X on the perimeter of the grid. If R reaches the square X before it's caught by C1 or C2, then R successfully escapes. Else, R is unable to escape.

As input we are provided: Values of m (number of rows) and n (number of columns), initial coordinates for R, C1, C2, and a list of inaccessible squares.

I) Using the input provided, how can you use an adjacency list to construct a graph to solve the problem. Analyze the runtime of graph creation.

I was actually thinking of using a adjacency matrix because of the grid representation, but we are asked to use and adjacency list. As a result, I'm confused on what should be considered a vertex and edge in this problem. I was think that every square in the grid will be a vertex and its edges will be all of its neighboring squares, at least the ones it can reach, 4 squares being the maximum. So should my adjacency list store ALL m by n pairs and then for every pair maintain a linked list of neighbors, i.e. squares reachable? If I went with this route there will be (m * n) vertices, and then for each of those I would have to check which squares are reachable (up, down, left, right) and whether that square is inaccessible, so I would have to scan through the inaccessible list provided as input which would take O(n) time. So I guess that would put me up to O(m*n) running time for graph creation. Can I do better than this?

II) Given the graph you create in part (I) describe an algorithm to check if R can escape.

*Assumption: The strategy that R, C1 and C2 is negligible. It doesn't matter if R,C1,C2 move in the "smart" way or completely random.

Since R declares its destination before the chase begins I think it's just a matter of whether there exists a path from where R starts at to its destination square. So can I get away with running DFS and check if R can reach its destination? But, I don't know R will be able to avoid C1 and C2.

Guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Sheesh. The [tag:dfs] tag even _specifically_ notes that it is **not** to be confused with "depth-first-search". Sigh...

Comment: Your assumption for II is completely incorrect. Suppose, for example, all grid squares are obstacles except for a path from R to C1 (where C1 is on the square X). Then it's completely impossible for the robber to escape despite the fact the robber has a path to X. I think a reasonable assumption to make would be that the robber would always take as direct a path as possible to the goal, since if the cop could catch up to the robber's current square, it can also reach X at the same time as the robber, so you can reduce the problem to which of the two sides can reach X first.

Comment: I think that for R to escape it needs to find an X were the distance of R to **any point** on the path to X is shorter than c1 && c2 distance to the same point.

Comment: @c0der for R to escape it must land on a square that lives on the perimeter of the grid. So should R look for the square on the perimeter in which its closest to? Or should R explore all the squares on the perimeter and see if it can reach there?

Comment: @MichaelHuang R no longer declares a square it wants to reach. Instead, R can only escape if it manages to land on a square on the perimeter of the grid.

Comment: I think that what I wrote _for R to escape it needs to find an X were the distance of R to **any point** on the path to X is shorter than c1 && c2 distance to the same point_  applies to any point on the escape path, and not only X.  If the path contains a point closer to c1 or c2 than to R, than the cops will catch the robber at that point. You may want to [edit] you question to remove the assumption and ask for advice about the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you pretty much know how to build the graph, but it's better to give each vertex a number instead of maintaining (m,n) tuples.

1. Allocate an array of N * M lists.  Each position (x,y) on the grid will correspond to slot x+n*y in that array.  That slot will contain a list of adjacent accessible numbers or null if its an obstacle.
2. For now, initialize the array with an empty list at every position
3. For each obstacle, set its corresponding array slot to null.
4. For grid position (x,y), if its a vertex `(array[x+n*y]!=null)`, then check its neighbors to fill out its adjacency list.  If `array[x+1+n*y]!=null`, for example, then the list at `[x+n*y]` would include `[x+1+n*y]`.

The resulting representation is pretty compact and good for many purposes.  Since the vertexes have degree <= 4, an adjacency list is much more efficient than an adjacency matrix.

The remaining part of your program will be greatly simplified as well, since it doesn't have to deal with coordinates or know anything about the original grid.

Unfortunately, the "*Assumption" takes all the fun out of the second part.

Comment: That is interesting. Ignoring the assumption can you elaborate on the path finding algorithm ? (see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60860608/how-to-build-a-graph-from-cops-and-robber-problem#comment107681095_60860608))

Comment: Without the assumption, you would use minimax to search the graph of states, where each state has two cop positions and one robber position.  You could then determine whether or not the robber can escape if the cops play optimally.  The game graph can be large, and it would be important to represent your board graph in a way that facilitates the minimax search.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax